# Spring MongoDB BasicQuery not working with projection

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have following BasicQuery

```
BasicQuery query2 = new BasicQuery("{status:{$in:['APPROVED','NEW','OPEN']}},{siteId:1,_id:0}");
```

Where BasicQuery is a class from SpringData mongoDb org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery. While doing the debug the above query get compiled into

```
Query: { "status" : { "$in" : [ "APPROVED" , "NEW" , "OPEN"]}}, Fields: null, Sort: { }
```

But it should have been compiled as below

```
Query: { "status" : { "$in" : [ "APPROVED" , "OPEN" , "NEW"]}}, Fields: { "siteId" : 1 , "_id" : 0}, Sort: null
```

If you notice, fields are still missing into compiled BasicQuery. Please help how i can have project in BasicQuery. I can have projection by using Query as below.

```
Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(STATUS).in(validStatus));
        query.fields().include("siteId").exclude("_id");
```

My query is how i can achieve the same using BasicQuery.

Answer (score 3):

I guess i got the answer. Instead of using single string argument constructor of BasicQuery we need to use two String argument basic query as follow.

```
BasicQuery query2 = new BasicQuery("{status:{$in:['APPROVED','NEW','OPEN']}}","{siteId:1,_id:0}");
```

Above will compile into following query

```
Query: { "status" : { "$in" : [ "APPROVED" , "OPEN" , "NEW"]}}, Fields: { "siteId" : 1 , "_id" : 0}, Sort: null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{ $and: [{ studentId: { $in: "+studentIds+" } }, { status: { $ne:  '"+studStatus+"'} }] }");
```

studentIds is an array and studStatus is a string!
Thanks to [vashishth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1568755/vashishth)